# Concating $_ in Pattern for regular expression in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to use the $_ in a Pattern in Powershell. I have the following script but it doesn't work

```
Get-Content ..\myfile.txt | ForEach-Object {
 
     $counter=(gc *.log | Select-String -Pattern '$_\/Directory\/Cars\/Sign.jpg')
}
```

If I run the script,  in lines of the myfile.txt which I know there is some ocurrences according to the Pattern it finds 0, so how I must write the $_ in the pattern?.

Thanks so much

Comment: Olaf  I am looking for the content of $_. Thanks

Comment: @zoit if you want `$_` to expand, you need an _expandable_ string literal (use double-quotes instead of single-quotes): `-Pattern "$_/Directory/Cards/Sign\.jpg"` (you also don't need to escape `/` in .NET's regex grammar). You might want to escape the input string itself: `-Pattern "$([regex]::Escape($_))/Directory/Cards/Sign\.jpg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason PowerShell isn't expanding `$_` is because you're using a *verbatim* string literal (a string literal defined using `'` single-quotes).

For an *expandable* string literal, you need to use `"` double-quotes - PowerShell will then attempt to expand variable expressions inside the string:

```
Get-Content ..\myfile.txt | ForEach-Objet {
     $counter=(gc *.log | Select-String -Pattern "${_}/Directory/Cars/Sign\.jpg")
}
```

Note: `${_}` is the same variable as `$_`.
The explicit `{}` qualifiers prevents PowerShell from interpreting something that isn't actually part of the variable name as such. Let's say your pattern looked like `"$_Sign\.jpg"`, PowerShell would attempt to resolve the token `$_Sign` instead of just `$_`, whereas `"${_}Sign\.jpg"` makes it obvious to PowerShell's parser where the variable expression ends.

---

Depending on what `myfile.txt` contains, you might want to escape the input string:

```
Get-Content ..\myfile.txt | ForEach-Object {
     $counter=(gc *.log | Select-String -Pattern "$([regex]::Escape($_))/Directory/Cars/Sign\.jpg")
}
```

For further reading on these topics, peruse the [`about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) and [`about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) help topics